# Sharepoint Online add existing group to document Libary with Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online

I like to create an Powershell script to Add an existing Office/azure group to an sharepoint online document libary
for SharePoint 2013 it isn't a problem but I can't find out how to do this on SharePoint Online
I have Office 365 groups and Azure groups
what i already have is that i break the inherentence so that all the groups are gone
but now how to add the existing groups to my document libary

Comment: PNP is your friend! https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps